# How to redirect php page with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my url using with .htaccess, i wanna redirect this url:

> https://my-domain/url.php/?u=https://www.google.com

to

> https://my-domain/?https://www.google.com

So i tried this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/url\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://nullrefer.cf/? [R=302,L]
```

But code is not working, it's not rewriting the URL

Comment: Not sure about the rewrite rule, but should the second domain there be https://my-domain/?u=https://www.google.com? As it looks like the first part of your query string has disappeared...

Comment: no second domain is not `/?u=` it's only `/?`

Comment: Ah, right, that means you need to change the query string as well - https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/ seems to have some useful information on that. When you say "it's not working", is it not rewriting your original URL at all, or is it rewriting it to the wrong thing?

Comment: The code actually not works, it's not rewriting the original URL